# The column is not valid in the select list because it is not contained in either the aggregate function or the GROUP by clause

Tags: sql

I have a table `user_purchases`

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| user_login |    date    |   product  |
+------------+------------+------------+
|    neo     | 31.03.2999 |     hat    |
+------------+------------+------------+
|  trinity   | 31.03.1999 | sunglasses |
+------------+------------+------------+
|    neo     | 01.04.2999 | sunglasses |
+------------+------------+------------+
|  trinity   | 01.04.1999 |     hat    |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

You must obtain the user's latest purchase.

```
SELECT
  user_purchases.user_login AS user_login,
  max(user_purchases.date) AS date
FROM user_purchases
GROUP BY user_purchases.user_login;
```

How to get the product?

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|    neo     | 01.04.2999 | sunglasses |
+------------+------------+------------+
|  trinity   | 01.04.1999 |     hat    |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+The+column+is+not+valid+in+the+select+list+because

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

One method uses a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select up.*
from user_purchases up
where up.date = (select max(up2.date)
                 from user_purchases up2
                 where up2.user_login = up.user_login
                );
```

Comment: can I get it in one request?

Comment: @YuriyBochkarev . . . I don't understand your comment.  This is one query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from user_purchases 
where date = (select max(date) 
              from user_purchases)
```

Comment: need aggregation by users

Comment: select user from user_purchases 
where date = (select max(date) 
              from user_purchases) group by user

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_purchases 
WHERE date = MAX(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%d-%Y'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common table expression.

```
;WITH Foo 
AS
(
   SELECT
     up.user_login AS user_login,
     max(up.date) AS date
   FROM 
      dbo.user_purchases up
   GROUP BY 
      up.user_login
)
SELECT 
   Foo.*,
   up.product
FROM 
   Foo
JOIN 
   user_purchases up 
ON 
up.user_login = Foo.user_login AND
up.date = Foo.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (if your RDBMS supports it) is to use the `DENSE_RANK` (or `RANK`) window function:

```
    WITH 
    -- sample data
    user_purchases(user_login, [date], product) AS
    (
                    SELECT 'neo', '1999-03-31', 'hat'
        UNION ALL   SELECT 'trinity', '1999-03-31', 'sunglasses'
        UNION ALL   SELECT 'neo', '1999-04-01', 'sunglasses'
        UNION ALL   SELECT 'trinity', '1999-04-01', 'hat'
    )
    -- CTE for ranked data
    ,ranked_purchases AS
    (
        SELECT *, 
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_login ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS rnk
        FROM user_purchases
    )
-- actual query
SELECT * FROM ranked_purchases
WHERE rnk = 1
```